# TSQL: Get all tables affected by Cascade Delete

Tags: t-sql, cascade

I'm looking for a SQL script that will list all tables that will be affected when deleting a record from table X.
It should also list the dependent tables affected down the "tree" as the affected tables will have cascade deletes to other, which in turn will affect others etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate a full hierarchy of tables affected, e.g.

```
WITH OnDelete AS
(   SELECT f.parent_object_id,
            f.referenced_object_id,
            RecursionLevel = 1,
            ObjectTree = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONCAT(OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id), ' --> ', OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id)))
    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
    WHERE f.delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  od.parent_object_id,
            f.referenced_object_id,
            od.RecursionLevel + 1,
            ObjectTree = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONCAT(od.ObjectTree, ' --> ', OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id)))
    FROM    OnDelete AS od
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS f
                ON f.parent_object_id = od.referenced_object_id
                AND f.delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE'

)
SELECT  BaseTable = OBJECT_NAME(od.parent_object_id),
        OnDelete = od.ObjectTree
FROM    OnDelete AS od
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    OnDelete AS ex
            WHERE   ex.parent_object_id = od.parent_object_id
            AND     ex.ObjectTree LIKE CONCAT(od.ObjectTree, '%')
            AND     LEN(ex.ObjectTree) > LEN(od.ObjectTree)
        )
ORDER BY od.parent_object_id;
```

This will output something like:

| BaseTable | OnDelete |
| --- | --- |
| T2 | T2 --> T1 |
| T3 | T3 --> T2 --> T1 |
| T4 | T4 --> T3 --> T2 --> T1 |
| T5 | T5 --> T4 --> T3 --> T2 --> T1 |

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03de607994ef8a7bd46f4e4706582d06)**

Comment: Thanks. It works from the many to one side. Is it possible to do it from the one to many side? I.e. I would like to see all the tables who will also have data removed if I delete from T2.

Comment: This should also work for that (unless I am mis-understanding), it will generate a new row for each cascade path, e.g. [In this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcf22f050fe892f2d64330f05153f103), `T5` generates two paths  - `T5 --> T3 --> T1` and `T5 --> T4 --> T2`, as T5 links to two tables (`T3` and `T4`) which in turn each link to a further table (`T1` and `T2`)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and describe it a bit better. Your answer is not wrong- I'm just looking for an enhancement if I may. In your example (line 2), data from T2 and T3 will be removed if a record in T1 is dropped. Is it possible to "swop" it. I.e. Base Table should be T1 (that's my top node) and then I want to see in OnDelete T2 --> T3. Example: Col 1: Student.  Column 2: Student --> Subjects --> Score.  At the moment it will show Score in Column 1 with Score --> Subject --> Student in Column 2.

Comment: To swap it all round you basically just need to swap the references around (eg. instead of `f.parent_object_id = od.referenced_object_id` to traverse down the tree, instead use `f.referenced_object_id = od.parent_object_id` to traverse up the tree. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d88d5cf03ef38e2fdb43d4c2adff1fb)

Comment: Great, thanks. I do get an error that "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.". I guess there are child-parent relationship in a table on itself. But your answer is what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: Great answer, upvoted ! This is what I was searching for. To be perfect it would have been nice to have the schema before table names (I am dealing with a huge database), but it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- using sys tables to enumerate foreign keys
    SELECT
        f.name constraint_name
       ,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) referencing_table_name
       ,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) referencing_column_name
       ,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) referenced_table_name
       ,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) referenced_column_name
       ,delete_referential_action_desc
       ,update_referential_action_desc
    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
       ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
    ORDER BY f.name
```

Comment: This does give the relationships, but not all the tables down the cascading tree. I.e. table 1 deletes from table2 and table 2 deletes from table 3 and 4, while cascades to 5 etc.